# Calculate the absolute value difference in work function for two diodes

Tags: semiconductors, homework

> Given two semiconductor diodes where one is silicon and the other is called Graham, and both are connected by ideal wires that do not affect their work functions, and they are also in thermal equilibrium with each other.
> Considering the temperature is 300 Kelvin.
> Calculate the absolute value of the differences in the work function between the diodes in electron volts.
> The energy gap is independent of temperature in both diodes.
> Hint: What is the definition of the Fermi level in intrinsic semiconductors?
> Also given that:
> \$Eg(Graham) = 1.8 [eV]\$
> \$m^*_h(Graham) = 0.5m_0\$
> \$m^*_e(Graham) = 0.066m_0\$
> \$Eg(si)=1.12[eV]\$
> \$m^*_h(si)=0.81m_0\$
> \$m^*_e(si)=1.18m_0\$
> Where \$m^*\$ represents the effective mass.
> The answer is \$0.303\$

There is no reference, its a Academic course from my university, we do not have any book or something related, its just lectures and practices.

I tried maybe thinking that because the metals are the same, so I just have to calculate the \$phi_s\$ and \$phi_{graham}\$ and thus I receive:
\$phi_s=0.56\$
\$phi_{graham}=0.9\$
And then just subtract them and receive \$0.34\$, which is the wrong answer, but close to the original question, so I guess I am missing something.
We know that \$V_f\$ is 0 since it is intrinsic.
If my way at the  beginning at wrong, there is a way to calculate \$phi_{ms}\$ by using \$א_s\$, but there is not way of calculating \$א_s\$ or \$א_{graham}\$

Comment: No drawing or diagram, so I am still struggling to imagine what the problem actually proposes. Sounds like to independent junction diodes (but might be Schottky, for all I can tell) with perfect conductors (whatever that is) providing connection between P and P and also N and N, in parallel. No idea what Graham is, but either is randomly named substance or else is Germanium. And you have no book, either. You may be in the wrong place. Just a thought.

Comment: Hi, the question does not have a drawing or a diagram. I translated the question one by one, from my language to English. made sure it is right by using translation + ChatGPT and saw it is sounding correct. Regarding Schottky, actually we did not really touch that at that course, we heard it once ,but only once ( not related to this topic ). Graham is a made up semiconductor, you dont have to mind, its just a semiconductor that has the given values ( it could be called however you want ). Not germanium of course.
Regarding wrong place, sadly there is no other stack for semiconductors.

Comment: By `wrong place` I only meant `wrong class`. Not wrong place to ask a question.